# A simple JavaScript / jQuery way of swapping the positioning of two image links on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set up a client-side translation of my web page using `translate.js`. If a user clicks on say, French, I would like that to move to the position of English and for English to move to the position of French. I tried the following:

```js
$('.img-btn').click(function(){
    var clickedId = $(this).attr('src');
    alert('you clicked on button #' + clickedId);
    $('.img-btn.active').attr('src', clickedId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="language-select">
        <a class="lang_selector trn" href="#" role="button" data-value="fr"><img id="French" class="img-fluid rounded-circle img-btn" src="img/flags/fr.jpg" alt="French"></a>
        <a class="lang_selector trn" href="#" role="button" data-value="it"><img id="Italian" class="img-fluid rounded-circle img-btn" src="img/flags/it.jpg" alt="Italian"></a>
        <a class="lang_selector trn" href="#" role="button" data-value="en"><img id="English" class="img-fluid rounded-circle img-btn active" src="img/flags/en.jpg" alt="English"></a>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true">
    </div>
```

But it doesn't seem to work (not even the alert did). Any ideas?

Comment: When do you call that code? You might be calling it before the elements have been made

Comment: jquery `.detach()` and `.append()`.

Comment: please add absolute path of flag image

Comment: you want to change only src or complete link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good afternoon,

I think you want something like this:

```
    $('.lang_selector').click(function(){
      var clickedId = $(this).children(':first').attr('src');
      alert('you clicked on button #' + clickedId);

      var lastChild = $('div#language-select > i:last-child');
      var lastLink = $('div#language-select > a:last-of-type');

      //Insert current clicked element to last position
      lastChild.before($(this));

      //Insert the element that was last before the first element
      $('div#language-select > a:first-of-type').before(lastLink);

    });
```

Comment: This worked for me - mostly. I had to make a slight alteration to the HTML and place those `<i>`s in a separate div as the `lastChild` kind of messed the order up. There is still an issue whereby after playing with them for a while they just go to the next available position, instead of the last, but I'm fine with that for now!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like this. [Live link](https://jsfiddle.net/yknk6j77/)

```js
$('.img-btn').click(function(){
    var clickedSrc = $(this).attr('src');
    var activeSrc=$('.img-btn.active').attr('src');
    alert('you clicked on button #' + clickedSrc);
    $('.img-btn.active').attr('src', clickedSrc);
    $(this).attr('src', activeSrc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="language-select">
        <a class="lang_selector trn" href="#" role="button" data-value="fr"><img id="French" class="img-fluid rounded-circle img-btn" src="http://www.theodora.com/gif2/france_fan.jpg" alt="French"></a>
        <a class="lang_selector trn" href="#" role="button" data-value="it"><img id="Italian" class="img-fluid rounded-circle img-btn" src="http://www.theodora.com/flags/new9/italy-s.gif" alt="Italian"></a>
        <a class="lang_selector trn" href="#" role="button" data-value="en"><img id="English" class="img-fluid rounded-circle img-btn active" src="http://www.theodora.com/flags/new12/bangladesh-s.gif" alt="English"></a>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true">
    </div>
```

Comment: While this is something that I thought would work - it just didn't for whatever reason. The answer below worked for me though. Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score -1):

put your function in ready document or use the bubbling concept  like so , to make sure the code will applied after the page creation :

```
$('body').on('click','.img-btn',function(){
    var clickedId = $(this).attr('src');
    alert('you clicked on button #' + clickedId);
    $('.img-btn.active').attr('src', clickedId);
});
```